# Theme is not applied inside my adapter

Tags: android, listview, themes

I am trying to create a simple activity with a ListView (code below)

The Activity is using Theme.Light, but it seems that the simple_list_item_2 is the one for a dark theme.

The result in unreadable text.

Is there a way to use a Light Theme on my ListView?

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, array) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                TwoLineListItem row;
                if(convertView == null){
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    row = (TwoLineListItem)inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, null);
                }else{
                    row = (TwoLineListItem)convertView;
                }
                String[] data = this.getItem(position).split(";");
                //No check on data.length for the example.
                row.getText1().setText(data[0]);
                row.getText2().setText(data[1]);

                return row;

            }
        };
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

I used:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
```

instead of

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```